# How do I see if an array index I'm accessing is out of range of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, indexoutofboundsexception

Is there anyway I can use some boolean expression to see if what I want to access is out of bounds?

Comment: Use use the `length` property of the array.  E.g. for iterating an array we can avoid out of bounds using the pattern `for (int i=0; i < array.length; ++i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have array like this(int[] a = new in[10]) you can test it like

```
if(index < a.length)
```

or if you have `ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();` you can test it like

```
if( index < b.size())
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct boolean expression to check if an `index` is out of bounds for array `array` is:

```
index < 0 || index >= array.length
```

As in:

```
if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) {
    System.out.println("Index is out of bounds");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.length to find the length of the array and then compare your index with array.length (it should be less than length of array and greater or equal to 0).
As the index surpasses length java gives you exception(ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception).

```
   //let i be the index
```

if(i >= array.length || i<0)
   //you will get an error

Answer (score -1):

You can always check if the index you are trying to use can be accessed by doing this:

`if(index >= 0 and index <= array.length−1)`   //This checks to see if the index you are going to use is greater or equal to 0 (since you cant access a negative index) and make sure it is less than the maximum size of the whole array)